# *ngSwitchCase is rendering only the *ngDefault

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two components that must be renderized by a expression:

**HTML:**

```
<div *ngFor="let avaliacao of avaliacoes" [ngSwitch]="escolha_layout_avaliacao">
      <app-avaliacao-produto-modelo-emoji *ngSwitchCase="emoji" [avaliacao]="avaliacao"></app-avaliacao-produto-modelo-emoji>
      <app-avaliacao-produto *ngSwitchDefault [avaliacao]="avaliacao"></app-avaliacao-produto>
</div>
```

**TS:**

```
escolha_layout_avaliacao: string

ngOnInit() {
  this.buscaDadosLayout()
}

buscaDadosLayout(){
  this.escolha_layout_avaliacao = "emoji"
}
```

But the `*ngSwitch` is only rendering the default option, ignoring the condition that have the value "emoji".

If i put in my html: `{{escolha_layout_avaliacao}}` i have the value "emoji", but the `*ngSwitchCase` only render the default case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument you provide to *ngSwitchCase will be evaluated on your component's scope. So if you pass emoji, it will compare with the value of emoji variable which does not exist in your case.

Try it with string literals: *ngSwitchCase="'emoji'"